# How to convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For example

```
    private void tab_Control_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (TabControl)sender;
        Selected_tab(tab_Control.SelectedTab.Name);
    }

    void Selected_tab(string tabname)
    {
        TabPage _tabname = tabname; // Error need to be converted 

        this.tab_Control.SelectedTab = _tabname;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can write

```
tab_Control.SelectedTab = tab_Control.TabPages[tabname];
```

In general, if you know that the control you're looking for is directly inside of some container (such as a `GroupBox` or the form itself), you can write

```
someContainer.Controls[controlName];
```

If you don't know what the control's parent is, you can write

```
this.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
```

The second parameter tells it to recursively search all containers.